# What is 'Fiscal Period'?

Tags: forecast, fiscal-periods

This seems to be a field only accessible via Reporting or Forecasting, but I can't seem to understand how it's set.

Anyone have any info on this?

Edit:

Just created a new opp and it give it a Fiscal Period of Q4-2019 despite having a Close Date of 11/13. It's showing up incorrectly in Forecasts.

[image]

Comment: Anyone?! Bump!!